# MotionLayout not recognizing

Tags: android, android-layout, android-motionlayout

I added library for **Motion Layout**

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha3'
```

but with add `MotionLayout` in layout file it is not recognizing the layout.

```
Error inflating class android.support.constraint.motion.MotionLayout
```

Answer (score 3):

You're importing an AndroidX/JetPack Dependency but using the old reference to MotionLayout. The MotionLayout class is now located here:

> androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout

Do a clean build using `gradlew clean` as well to clean up the caches :)

Comment: yes i did that but i have to add kolin import as well in order to make it work properly

Answer (score 1):

I too faced the issue. I was not able to see the layout design in my preview screen for motion layout.

My app level gradle dependencies were:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha03'
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0-alpha05'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha3'
```

And the layout file was: `<android.support.constraint.motion.MotionLayout ... />`

When i changed it to: `androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout` it worked normally.

Comment: If by java you mean can you use in code? then yes. It works like how other layout works. Eg:
     `MotionLayout container = findViewById(R.id.container);
     button1.setOnClickListener((v) -> {
                container.setTransition(R.id.start1, R.id.end1);
                container.transitionToEnd();
            });`